# Weblogic SingletonService interface implementation. Thread is running on both managed server

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic, weblogic12c

I implemented `SingletonService` interface which is located inside weblogic API. This interface assure that the class which implements this interface is run only on one managed server. In my case I have two threads inside `activate()` method on `SingletonService` implementation class. The `singletonService` in migrated but threads are running as is on that server and it make duplicate entry inn my database.

When I do kill and restart on `weblogic` till some time the thread runs on both the server and some time run on one server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really simple trick to resolve this issue. I come to know How to stop thread.
And I used same logic to stop the execution when `SingletonService` is deactivated.
In `deactivate()` we added logic to stop the thread. We added simple flag it will helpful to break the execution of thread.

> sample code

```
public void deactivate(){
 // take reference of thread and break the execution of thread 
 // call thread.interrupt();
}
```

This is the simple trick I used to solve my problem.